# Checking whether two quadratic equations have a common zero

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, algebraic-complexity, quadratic

Given two quadratic equations (with integer coefficients):

$x^T A_1 x+ b^T_1 x + c_1=0$ and $x^T A_2 x+ b^T_2 x + c_2=0$

The problem is to decide whether they have a common zero.  Here $x$ is a vector of real numbers, i.e., we are looking for real solutions.

Q: what is the complexity of this problem?

What we know is that checking whether a *family* of quadratic equations has a common zero is $\exists R$-complete. However, the current question restricts the family size to be 2. A natural question arises: is this problem simpler, or remains to be $\exists R$-complete?

A related question is here: [Zero of a multivariate cubic equation](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/34139)

Comment: I'm guessing from the context that the $x$ is meant to be a vector of reals?

Comment: $x$ is a vector otherwise the problem would be a bit trivial.

Comment: Is x a vector _of reals_? ​ (as opposed to, say, rationals or complex numbers) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: it is a convention that we are looking for real solutions.

Comment: Are you aware of any proof that your problem is NP-hard? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I don't know about the two equation case (or even a fixed constant). But, subset sum with n integers reduces to $n+1$ equations via the binary-enforcing $x_i(1-x_i)=0$ equations.